# Find The Value of An Argument Without Executing The File

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to scan a python file and figure out the value of an **argument** to a function. Take for example a file containing following code.

```
# start of file
path = "/a/b/c"
def main():
    run(full_path=path, os="linux")
# end of file
```

> I need to know what is the value of argument **"full_path"** without executing or importing this file.

I think any library which is used in developing IDEs can do it. Please help in case you have solved similar problems.

To give a little bit of background to the problem, I am running a server application hence cannot afford to execute any arbitrary python file and also I may not have all the related dependent packages in my environment in order to execute.

Comment: "I am running a server application hence cannot afford to execute any arbitrary python file" - are you doing this for security purposes? This is pretty much guaranteed to be insecure.

Comment: Are you concerned about determining if the argument is ultimately coming from an outside source (environment, config file, command-line argument, etc) or just finding where in the code a hard-coded value might have been set?

Comment: Yes it is technically possible that "value" may be coming inside via "import" of something. But it my case it is 99.9% certain that value will be constructed in the same file and in the "main" scope.